# How to determine if result of two integer numbers is integer of float?

Tags: c++, integer

I'm trying to determine if result is integer, when I divide two integer numbers. How do I do that?

```
float result;
int number1, number2;
cout<<"Give me number 1 and 2"<<endl;
cin>>number1;
cin>>number2;
result = number1 / number2;
if(result == int)
{
   cout<<"The numbers can be devided"<<endl;
}else cout<<"The numbers can't be devided"<<endl;
```

I get error, because you can't do it like that, can somebody give me a hand? It's bugging me as hell, and every post keeps telling me, how to check if input is integer, not the result. I don't care about input, I want to know if the result is integer. Thanks for help!

Edit:

So my function looks like this:

```
int funkcijaDva()
{
    int popizdobom = 0;
    int tri = 3;
    int tristo = 300;
    int tritisoc = 3000;
    float result;
    for(; tristo!=tritisoc;tristo++)
    {
        result = (int)tristo / tri;
        if(tri % tristo == 0)
        {
            popizdobom++;
        }
    }
    return popizdobom;
}
```

and the result at popizdobom is always 0... Am I doing something wrong?
EDIT:
Got it to work... something wrong with compiler I guess...

Comment: Write 100 times: "C is not C++ is not C!".

Comment: result of operation on two `int`s will always be `int`

Comment: It's actually a legit question as nobody in my class knows how to solve it, so stop being so negative about it...

Comment: "Nobody in my class...." does not make it legit **here**. However, the problem is not the question as such, but that you do not provide the  information.

Comment: I dont understand why so many negative votes for this question? If you don't like the question or you think its too basic then don't answer it...and if u do then give proper explanation for your negative votes...

Comment: @anurag86: Perhaps this is homework and OP should have better litened to the lessons, or at least ask his teacher?

Comment: @Olaf in fact not a homework. I'm trying to build one of my old programs in c++. :)

Comment: So you should know how you did in the original. Which language? The modulo-operation is very widely availabe, even in larger CPU instructions.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't know about modulo operation, I used a method that requires 2 inputs and returns you with a number of possible divisions (how many numbers can you divide)... I wanted to do my own method this time (mostly because I couldn't find any)

Comment: That is basic computer arithmetics knowledge; not even programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can check it easily with the **modulo** operator (`%`), which finds the remainder after the division of one number by another:

```
if(number1 % number2 == 0) 
{
  // result of division is integral 
  // or in other words: number1 / number2 = whole number
}
```

Note that `number1` and `number2` have to be integers in order for modulo to work.

You will also have to cast at least one of your integers to `float`, in order to get a `float` as the result of their division.

```
float result = (float)number1 / number2;
```

You can read more about the **modulo** operator here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

---

*EDIT:* Incorporated some of the suggestions from the comments below.

Comment: Once you divide, it's too late. You really want to check before you divide.

Comment: no, I need to know if my result is integer or not... And I don't know what you just did here...

Comment: @AlexVandalowski I use the modulo operator, which in C and C++ is written as %. you can read more about this operator on wikipedia. (I provided a link).

Comment: @AlexVandalowski: How about doing some research on your own? "C operators" will find all information you need. Do not rely on others explaining you every little bit.

Comment: @AlexVandalowski As others wrote, if you operate on ints you will get back an int. E.g. `5 / 2` is `2` in C++, not `2.5`. By comparison, `5.0 / 2` is `2.5`. If you really want to do floating point division on two int variables, use `(float) number1 / number2` before assigning the result to your `result` variable. Then the question changes into a completely different one: "how do I check whether a float value is integer?". Still, the reasonable thing to do is use modulo, as this answer shows.

Comment: @Olaf how about you stop giving me such a hard time? I'd like to see you do some other programming language for the first time... It's hard when everything is in English and you're not a native speaker... So stop being so irritated by my not knowledge.
Miguel, thanks

Comment: @AlexVandalowski what is your problem? 100 % 10 = 0 while 95 % 10 = 5 etc.. the % gives the remainder after the division.

Comment: @AlexVandalowski: Learning programming **is** a hard time! As much as learning wood-work or building a house. There is nothing for free. And I **am** not a native speaker (my English should make this clear already) and I did learn programming where there was no internet available, there were no books available I could afford, and there was no one I could ask. Try learning with machine language (binary codes, not Assembler) and then we talk again.

Comment: @Olaf Well good for you, I guess... But I couldn't. Also, I do know binary, nothing special. Lp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually evaluate the division then you'll need to do it in floating point. You can do this by writing

`double f = 1.0 * number1 / number2;`

The `1.0` forces the division to take place in floating point.

You can then check if `f` is a whole number by evaluating `ceil(f) == f`. (Note that this is a legitimate usage of an exact floating point comparison).

If, on the other hand, you need to know if `number1 / number2` *would* yield a remainder, then evaluate `number1 % number2`. This will be non-zero if, and only if, `number1` does not divide exactly by `number2`.

Comment: I need to know if number1 / number2 = whole number. I don't know how else to say it... Ex. 5/6 != int where 5/5 = int & 10/5 = int, but 5/10 != int...

Comment: number1 / number2 is a whole number if, and only if, number1 % number2 is 0.

Comment: Second way to check it  ->  The two numbers for division are int's. You are storing the result in float. Lets call it `float fResult`. Lets again declare one more int variable as `int iResult = int1/int2`. Then check if `iFloat>iResult`. If yes that means the result is in float(that means greater than .0 )

Comment: @anurag86: I don't like that method (i) it breaks for negative numbers and (ii) floating point precision can give you headaches. `ceil` is a better approach.

Comment: No doubt what Bathsheba told is way better than my approach.

Comment: Sorry but -1: checking for equality of floating point numbers is a bad idea!

Comment: @ThomasSparber: No it isn't: it's absolutely fine if you know what you're doing. `ceil(f) == f` is one such case. Indeed, if you're doing lots of floating calculations that introduce imprecision, then you do need to compare with tolerance, and the calculation of that tolerance is as important as the calculation itself.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Ah ok sorry, I didn't know that. Please add this to your answer so I can remove the "-1"

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
int result;
int number1, number2;
cout<<"Give me number 1 and 2"<<endl;
cin>>number1;
cin>>number2;
result = number1 % number2;
if(result == 0)
{
   cout<<"The numbers can be devided"<<endl;
}else cout<<"The numbers can't be devided"<<endl;
```

Comment: Homework help is one thing. But you should explain at least.